# rsync how to send folder contents but not folder itself

Tags: rsync

Currently I have the following command which will send a folder and it's contents recursively:

```
rsync -avz --ignore-existing --recursive /var/-iles/_site root@mytestingdomain.com:/var/www
```

What I want is only the contents of folder `_site` to be sent to folder `www`
, not the `_site` folder itself.

Is it possible to send only the contents of folder `_site` via rsync?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using shell globbing:

```
rsync -avz --ignore-existing --recursive /var/-iles/_site/* root@mytestingdomain.com:/var/www/
```

All the contents of the `/var/-iles/_site/` directory will be copied to the destination.

Comment: if there were hidden files (i.e. beginning with a .) these are missed off with this command.